# always trigger "change"-event for <select>, even if the select2-option clicked is already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a native `<select>`-element based on which I'm initializing a select2-dropdown-menu.
I bound a change-event via select2 which is called whenever the select2/select-option is changed. However, I need to fire the event even if the currently selected option is selected again.

```
function onSelectChange(){
    alert('changed');
};

$("#select").select2().bind('change', onSelectChange);
```

I prepared a http://jsfiddle.net/rb6pH/1/ - if "Alaska" is currently selected and then selected again via the select2-dropdown, onSelectChange() should fire again, triggering the alert.

I have a hard time expressing myself, please ask if something isn't clear enough.

Comment: I can't get to fiddle at the moment, can you post a link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: If you want to fire an event on every click, why not just use the `click()` *method*?

Comment: This doesn't sound like good UX design. If the value doesn't change the user probably wont expect anything else to change.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I def. hear you on that and basically agree, however the situation is a little more complicated; thus, I need to trigger 'change' even when nothing is changed :(

Comment: Can you explain your situation? Maybe there is some other event you can listen to.

Comment: There is a mousedown event being listened to inside the plugin that detects whether or not the change event needs to be triggered. you're going to need to override that event to instead trigger it anyway. https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js#L1882

Comment: @DavidThomas I need to fire the event whenever an option is selected via the select2-dropdown, which, as far as I understand, happens via `change`, not `click`

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'll try: I'm using multiple select2-dropdowns to switch/display page content dynamically. Each select2-dropdown represents the navigation for a different content-category. Furthermore, I use a transparent element placed above the left part of the select2-element to capture clicks to the select2-element so that only the dropdown-arrow to the far right of the select2-element actually triggers the select2-dropdown; a click on the transparent element displays the content corresponding to the currently selected select2-option.

Comment: Sorry, that makes absolutely no sense at all. It's 2013, you shouldn't be working with transparent elements to capture clicks anymore.

Comment: I think you should ask a question about the problem you're trying to solve (with this covoluted approach), rather than how to deal with the problems created by the solution you're trying. Further, please take a look at the '[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)'

Comment: @FritsvanCampen However, the user still may use the select2-dropdown to select an option. If the users last selection had been in dropdown B and he then wants to select the option in dropdown A which is already selected, the change-event needs to trigger. I hope at least the explanation makes sense - I know using select2 here does not, however the design choice to even use select2 here currently is beyond my reach :(

Comment: So your selectboxes also act as navigation tabs? Make your own dropdownbox. The default ones don't have the behavior you want, they also don't look like navigation elements.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I absolutely agree; but as stated in my last comment I really have no choice but going with what there is, which is select2 (used for something it wasn't designed for in the first place). You're absolutely correct with your criticism regarding using select2 as navigation tabs (even if I made them look like navigation elements ;-)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636302/attach-click-event-to-element-in-select2-result). I have made a fiddle for your question based on the code in the link.
http://jsfiddle.net/rb6pH/55/

```
function onSelectChange(){
alert('changed');
};

var select2 = $("#select").select2().data('select2');

select2.onSelect = (function(fn) {
return function(data, options) {
    var target;

    if (options != null) {
        target = $(options.target);
    }

    if (target) {
        onSelectChange();
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
})(select2.onSelect);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel, works like a charm. Ironically, the "similar question" was asked by me, too :/
Did you see the answer I just gave myself, using the "close"-event? Which approach do you find more healthy?

Comment: If you open the dropdown then click outside of it the close event will stil fire. If you want an alert to appear even if they don't select anything then I think close would be fine.

Comment: Just what I realized myself this very moment (by fiddling around with the actually application code). Thanks so much again!

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be compatible with the latest version of select2 :(.

Answer (score 6):

Motivated by the absolutely valid remarks by @FritsvanCampen, I sat my ass down and figured out a way myself: What I really needed was a way to access the currently selected `val`, even if it hadn't changed. By using select2's undocumented `close`-event instead of `change`, I can access just that like so:

```
function onSelectChange(event){
    alert( $("#select").select2("val") );
};

$("#select").select2().bind('close', onSelectChange);
```

Find an updated jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rb6pH/42/

Comment: Still works with little adjustment: `select2:close` and `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might refer to this link, i stuck once in same situation,

Change event is not fired when the selection is changed using Select2's `val()` method.

The event object contains the following custom properties:

**val**

the current selection (taking into account the result of the change) - id or array of ids.

**added**

the added element, if any - the full element object, not just the id

**removed**

the removed element, if any - the full element object, not just the id

For more information you might refer to [this](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I read the question and it's so close to my problem so I decided not to post another question. What I want to do is after select2 closed, a simple text input become focused but it doesn't work. please check

```
function onSelectChange(){
    alert('closed');
    $('#hey').focus();
};

$("#select").select2().bind('close', onSelectChange);
$('#hey').on('focusin)', function(){alert('in');}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sobhanattar/x49F2/5/

I tried to make sure that the input become focused and it showed that the input become focused but I don't know why it doesn't show the curser

Answer (score 0):

a little old question but i spent a few hours last week to find a solution.

I am using Select2 version: 4.0.5.

My working solution is this one:

```
$("#exampleId").on("select2:open", function() {
    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        var $selectedChoiceInsideSelect2Dropdown = $("li.select2-results__option[id^='select2-" + exampleId + "-result'][aria-selected=true]");
        if ($selectedChoiceInsideSelect2Dropdown.length) {
            $selectedChoiceInsideSelect2Dropdown.on("mouseup", function() {
                $(this).trigger("change");
            });
            clearInterval(checkExist);
        }
    }, 100); // check every 100ms
});
```

It's very important to use the interval!

Answer (score -1):

```
 var prev_val = $('#select2').val();
 $('#select2').blur( function() {
    if( $(this).val() == prev_val )
       // not changed
    else {
       // changed
       prev_val = $(this).val();
    }
 });
```