# jQuery, trigger change also on already selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my `select`.
I want that the `already selected` option also triggers the `.change()` function.
Currently it triggers only when another option is selected.
How can I put this possibility without much Soucrecode. Maybe there is already a possibility I do not know.

[Here a fiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/G257s/1/)

**edit:**

I should perhaps mention that it should work on mobile browsers!

Comment: can you show your code?, to see what have you tried .

Comment: As event name is telling change only triggers on value change...

Comment: Q: Why do you need it to re-trigger on selecting the already selected item? From a UI perspective you would not expect an event to occur as nothing has changed.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.TK i already figureed that out...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i need it as refresh for the current option

Comment: @TimRücker are you just wanting the event to trigger for the default value? If so, just `.change()` after binding the event, [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/G257s/14/)

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales Does it work on mobile browsers?

Comment: Funny that something like this proves to be this hard, especially with different behaviour per browser. Here's another link that adresses multiple browsers (don't know about mobile): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207929/is-there-a-dom-event-that-fires-when-an-html-select-element-is-closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:***  IE doesn't handle it nicely! :(

To support IE, you could use:

### --DEMO--

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var con = $('#console');
    $('select').change(function () {        
        /* change also on already selected option */
        con.append('- ' + $(this).val() + '<br/>');
        //$(this).blur();
    }).change().bind('mousedown', function () {
        this.selectedIndex = -1;
        this.selectedIndex = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    });
});
```

See if that fits your needs:

### --DEMO--

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var con = $('#console');
    $('select').change(function () {        
        /* change also on already selected option */
        con.append('- ' + $(this).val() + '<br/>');
    }).change().bind('mousedown', function () {
        //on mousedown, clone SELECT element to display current selected value
        // this would be empty value otherwise when setting current selected index
        // NOTE: seems to be still not as good on IE...
        // FF would need to redefine some margin/padding
        if (!$(this).data('cloned')) $(this).data('cloned', $(this).clone().css({
            position: 'absolute',
            pointerEvents: 'none',
            top: this.offsetTop,
            left: this.offsetLeft,
            margin: 0
        }).appendTo('body'));
        // here set selectedIndex of SELECT element to not defined index
        // this would let on change event to be fired in all cases
        this.selectedIndex = -1;
    }).blur(function(){
        // on blur, remove cloned SELECT element and reset specific data object
        if ($(this).data('cloned')) {
            this.value = $(this).data('cloned').val();
            $(this).data('cloned').remove();
            $(this).data('cloned', null);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting... Can you explain how it works?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Set `this.selectedIndex = -1` to trigger onchange event on any option selected. Using cloned element for UI because otherwise SELECT reflected value would be empty. This needs more tests to see if that fits OP's needs. I'm not sure this would handle all expected cases

Comment: I think that fits my needs. If you could explain your code in your answer, I mark your answer as right.

Comment: I have to admit, that's pretty clever!

Comment: It is unfortunate the behavior is so ugly in IE. The click reaction and display are almost unusable. Maybe some tweaking for IE to make it perfect?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie this would work on IE: http://jsfiddle.net/G257s/20/ EDIT: still needs some shim for IE8 :(

Answer (score 0):

[**by Daniel Eidson**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486281/always-trigger-change-event-for-select-even-if-the-select2-option-clicked-i)

```
function onSelectChange(){
    alert('changed');
};

var select2 = $("#select").select2().data('select2');

select2.onSelect = (function(fn) {
    return function(data, options) {
        var target;

        if (options != null) {
            target = $(options.target);
        }

        if (target) {
            onSelectChange();
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
})(select2.onSelect);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rb6pH/129/)**

In HTML: add an `id` to select

```
<select id="select">
    <option selected>Selected</option>
    <option>Not selected</option>
</select>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: that doesnt work at all...its triggert to soon, before a slection is made

Comment: Please check the demo url, you will find that its working fine

Comment: It triggers on both clicking the select & options. @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: The OP wanted to trigger the event when the user either changes the options or not. So according to me this does the does. Its working in demo too

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated answer based on Daniel's response in another question

Comment: could you explain where you define the `.select2()` function?

Comment: It looks like it just replaces the Select with a new DOM. But it doesnt work on all mobile Browsers. Or rather, it does not behave like a normal select. Thank you anyway!