# Handle select2:select event on active option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I'm using Select2 4.0 and want to be able to handle when users click on the currently selected option, however Select2 doesn't appear to expose the `select2:selecting` or `select2:select` events on this option.

In the below code snippet I've added logging for the `select2:open`, `select2:selecting`, `select2:close` and `select2:select` events:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').select2({ placeholder: '' });
  
  $('select').on('select2:open', function(elem) {
    $('<li>').text('Open').appendTo('ol');
  });
  
  $('select').on('select2:selecting', function(elem) {
    $('<li>').text('Selecting...').appendTo('ol');
  });
  
  $('select').on('select2:close', function(elem) {
    $('<li>').text('Close').appendTo('ol');
  });
  
  $('select').on('select2:select', function(elem) {
    $('<li>').text('Selected "' + elem.target.value + '"').appendTo('ol');
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 256px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css">

<select>
  <option></option>
  <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
</select>

<ol></ol>
```

If we select "Foo", then select "Bar", then select "Bar" again, we'll get the following output:

[image: Example]

Upon selecting "Bar" the second time (whilst it's already selected), the `select2:selecting` and `select2:select` events are not exposed. These events would otherwise fall in position 10 and 12, moving the `select2:close` event to position 11.

I'm not that interested in `select2:selecting`, but is there any way to get the `select2:select` event to fire when a user clicks the already-elected option?

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486281/always-trigger-change-event-for-select-even-if-the-select2-option-clicked-i. Not sure  100% sure if this is compatible with the version you're using though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just tried the accepted solution on my local implementation and it doesn't appear to work on 4.0. I'm not sure if this is because the event names and data-attributes are different in 4.0 though. The other answer which triggers on `select2:close` won't really do the trick here as that'd cause the content to reload every even when the user makes no selection.