# stopPropagation is not working for select2 options in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to add a link in select2 options list. and I want to bind an event. It is working fine in chrome and firefox. But it is not working in IE(9/10/11). I tried all the alternatives, cancelbubble, returnValue But none is working.

When I click on the hyperlink with class `categoryDelete` It is propagating the event to li option and not even executing my custom mouseup event in IE.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636302/attach-click-event-to-element-in-select2-result) in stack overflow. I used `templateResult` for adding the link to select2 options. where as in the above link they used `formatResult`. Does it make any difference?

Here is my code.

```
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_tags").select2({
            dropdownParent: "#dropdownParent",
            placeholder: "Select category",
            templateResult: function (item) { return '<a href="javascript:;" class="categoryDelete"></a>' + item.text },
            escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m },
            allowClear: true,
            tags: true,
            closeOnSelect: false
        });


    // adding event for link inside select2 options li
    $(".categoryDelete").mouseup(function (event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert("clicked delete link");

    });
```

Comment: try `stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: You can also use `return false;` in your case for both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`

Comment: I also used `stopImmediatePropagation()` but no use. The thing is, it is not even triggering the custom event in IE. I even implemented `$.when().done()` in case if the event is binding before select2 is initialized. Something is wrong, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.categoryDelete` is getting generated dynamically and there is different way to add events to dynamically generated elements like one below:

```
$(document).on('mouseup','.categoryDelete',function (event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert("clicked delete link");
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between these two implementations?

Comment: dynamically created elements will not take events before its creation or if it is appended in later part to DOM. So you need to attach the event to document or to its parent element so that it will listen to this event onclick of that particular element!

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)