# Select2 does not keep the selected value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I made the search option on my site, using Select2 with custom list, everything work fine, the problem is that is always show first option selected, and I want to show the current option.

Used this link to do options of Select2 clickable: [Attach click-event to element in .select2-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636302/attach-click-event-to-element-in-select2-result)

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Real_Estate(string Tipo_Imovel_Search, string Localizacao_Search, string Tipologia_Search, string PrecoFrom, string PrecoTo, string AreaFrom, string AreaTo, string sortOrder, int? page)
{
    //Create List of RealEstateAllViewModel and fill it depend on searching strings
    var ApartmentsModel = new RealEstateAllViewModel();
    var ApartmentsList = ApartmentsModel.GetRegistos(Tipo_Imovel_Search, Localizacao_Search, Tipologia_Search, PrecoFrom, PrecoTo, AreaFrom, AreaTo);

    //sorting

    //Saved current sort variable for Paging List do not lose sorting in second page
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "preco_asc":
            ApartmentsList = ApartmentsList.OrderBy(s => s.Preco).ToList();
            break;
        case "preco_desc":
            ApartmentsList = ApartmentsList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Preco).ToList();
            break;
        case "area":
            ApartmentsList = ApartmentsList.OrderBy(s => s.Area_util).ToList();
            break;
```

In View:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            @*select order list*@
            <select class="search">
                <option value="@Url.Action("Real_Estate", "Apartamentos", new { sortOrder = "preco_asc", Tipo_Imovel_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipo_Imovel_Search"], Localizacao_Search = Request.QueryString["Localizacao_Search"], Tipologia_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipologia_Search"], PrecoFrom = Request.QueryString["PrecoFrom"], PrecoTo = Request.QueryString["PrecoTo"], AreaFrom = Request.QueryString["AreaFrom"], AreaTo = Request.QueryString["AreaTo"] })">
                    Preço (crescente)
                </option>
                <option value="@Url.Action("Real_Estate", "Apartamentos", new { sortOrder = "preco_desc", Tipo_Imovel_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipo_Imovel_Search"], Localizacao_Search = Request.QueryString["Localizacao_Search"], Tipologia_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipologia_Search"], PrecoFrom = Request.QueryString["PrecoFrom"], PrecoTo = Request.QueryString["PrecoTo"], AreaFrom = Request.QueryString["AreaFrom"], AreaTo = Request.QueryString["AreaTo"] })">
                    Preço (decrescente)
                </option>
                <option value="@Url.Action("Real_Estate", "Apartamentos", new { sortOrder = "area", Tipo_Imovel_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipo_Imovel_Search"], Localizacao_Search = Request.QueryString["Localizacao_Search"], Tipologia_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipologia_Search"], PrecoFrom = Request.QueryString["PrecoFrom"], PrecoTo = Request.QueryString["PrecoTo"], AreaFrom = Request.QueryString["AreaFrom"], AreaTo = Request.QueryString["AreaTo"] })">
                    Área (crescente)
                </option>
                <option value="@Url.Action("Real_Estate", "Apartamentos", new { sortOrder = "area_desc", Tipo_Imovel_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipo_Imovel_Search"], Localizacao_Search = Request.QueryString["Localizacao_Search"], Tipologia_Search = Request.QueryString["Tipologia_Search"], PrecoFrom = Request.QueryString["PrecoFrom"], PrecoTo = Request.QueryString["PrecoTo"], AreaFrom = Request.QueryString["AreaFrom"], AreaTo = Request.QueryString["AreaTo"] })">
                    Área (decrescente)
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".search").select2({
        language: "pt",
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity, //remove search box from single list
        templateResult: function (data) {
            if (data.id == null) {
                return data.text;
            }

            //used for allow click href in list
            var $listoption = $("<a>" + data.text + "</a > ");
            $listoption.prop("href", data.id);
            $listoption.on('mouseup', function (evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
            });

            return $listoption;
        }
    });
```

Everything work just fine: the URL change depend on search string : http://localhost:41350/pt/Apartamentos/Real_Estate?sortOrder=preco_asc

Controller return right orded list

The problem is that is always show first option selected, and I want to show the current option.

How can I make this?

Please help, I am a beginer in javascript. Thank you.

Comment: you may use: $("your select id").select2().select2('val','option value'); or you may add the attribute **selected** to the option in your view

Comment: Thank you for answer, I can use $("your select id").select2().select2('val','1'); but how do I catch current option value, by other word, how do I add selected=selected after person click on that option?