# How to Detect Clicked Event Handler on Select2 Element in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I tried to detect if the clicked element is `select2` and perform additional action as required not just opening dropdown list. But it is not successful as I clicked on `select2` element nothing happened.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2();

  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('select2')) {
      console.log('select2 element was just clicked');
    } else {
      console.log('you are not clicking on select2');
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.css" />

<select style="width:300px" id="select">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Central Time Zone">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I don't know why select2 does not receive clicked event. Is there any workaround solution archive this because I need to do more action when select2 was clicked? Thanks so much.

Comment: You should probably use one of the events the plugin provides, instead of trying to interfere with it from the outside. https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Comment: try $('select').select2().on() events , http://select2.github.io/select2/

Comment: @04FS, thanks, but from provided event does not include clicked event handler.  For some reasons, select2 element on device does not open on a single click, therefore, I tried to make it works, open, by make it open on click event on it.

Comment: That’s the wrong “therefore” here - you should rather investigate what causes the problem and then fix it, instead of trying to add workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? 
here's another example: https://jsfiddle.net/f8q2by55/ http://jsfiddle.net/6jaodjzq/

as stated in this answer: [Attach click-event to element in .select2-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636302/attach-click-event-to-element-in-select2-result)

> Because Select2 lib prevents any click events on popover list you can't bind events to .info directly. But you can redefine onSelect method and place there any code you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let selector = $('#select').select2()
     selector.onSelect = (function(fn) {
        return function(data, options) {
            console.log('selected');
        }
    })(selector.onSelect);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.css" />

<select style="width:300px" id="select">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Central Time Zone">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: basically without massive editing, you cannot add `on click` event to select2 js item, you only can easily access `onSelect `