# Allow the same value to be inserted in the text area several times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need your help please. I have a scenario where I appending value from the dropdown to the text area. I'm facing an issue where I cannot appending the same value from the dropdown.

For example I write at text area text `hello` then insert "**User name**" then try to insert "**User name**" again and it dose not inserted.. only another option I can insert. But if I insert another option then I can insert "**User name**" again.

```
<select name="email_admin" class="form-control variables_select">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>       
    <option value="user_name">User name</option>
   <option value="ticket_number">Ticket #</option>
   <option value="ticket_subject">Ticket subject</option>            
</select>

$('.variables_select').change(function(){
  var current_select_list = $(this).attr('id');
  var id = $(this).closest('.panel-body').find('textarea').attr('id');
  var cursorPosStart = $('#'+ id).prop('selectionStart');
  var cursorPosEnd = $('#'+ id).prop('selectionEnd');
  var v = $('#' + id).val();
  var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPosStart);
  var textAfter  = v.substring(cursorPosEnd, v.length);
  if ($('#' + current_select_list + ' option:selected').val().length > 0) {
      $('#' + id).val(textBefore + '{{' + $('#' + current_select_list + ' option:selected').val() + '}}' + textAfter);
  }
  $('#'+ id).prop('selectionStart', cursorPosStart);
  $('#'+ id).prop('selectionEnd', cursorPosStart + '{{' + $('#' + current_select_list + ' option:selected').val() + '}}'.length);
});
```

**html.**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="input-group pull-right margin-bottom-1">
      <?php
      echo Form::select('templates_variables_logs_staff', $templatesVariables, '', array('class' => 'form-control variables_select'));
      ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    echo Form::label('logs_staff', __('Content', 'notifications'), array('class' => 'control-label'));
    echo Form::textarea('logs_staff', $logs_staff, array('class' => 'form-control'));
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your html too, `textarea` and `panel-body`. we need to run your code. maybe it is good idea you create a working snippet

Comment: Alireza Ahmadi, change function dose not work when I choose the same option value.

Comment: I know I am telling you please show me your html code too. where is your textarea? where is your `panel-body`? and everything you've used in your script

Comment: Alireza Ahmadi, it is very complicated to show code.. it is a lot of php inside.

Comment: I only need some html code that is related to your script

Comment: Add html to topic.

Comment: I found the problem, that because you are using `change` event when you select `username` and again you select `username` you don't change the select box so it doesn't call your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are using `change` event when you select `username` and again you select `username` you don't **change** the select box value so it doesn't call your script.

If you need to add same value, you need to use `click` event instead of `change` event like this.

Note that `click` event may call your code multiple so you need to use some extra data to know this click is OK or not. To do that I've used extra attribute (say `clicks`) and check to see if has value is `1` or not. Also I need to reset the attribute value in `focusout` event:

```
 $('.variables_select').focusout(function () {
     $(this).data('clicks', 0);
 });
```

Here is working sample:

```js
 $('.variables_select').click(function () {
     if ($(this).data('clicks') == 1) {
         $(this).data('clicks', 0);

         var current_select_list = $(this).attr('id');
         var id = $('.panel-body').find('textarea').attr('id');
         var cursorPosStart = $('#' + id).prop('selectionStart');
         var cursorPosEnd = $('#' + id).prop('selectionEnd');
         var v = $('#' + id).val();
         var textBefore = v.substring(0, cursorPosStart);
         var textAfter = v.substring(cursorPosEnd, v.length);
         if ($('#' + current_select_list + ' option:selected').val().length > 0) {
             $('#' + id).val(textBefore + '{{' + $('#' + current_select_list + ' option:selected').val() + '}}' + textAfter);
         }
         $('#' + id).prop('selectionStart', cursorPosStart);
         $('#' + id).prop('selectionEnd', cursorPosStart + '{{' + $('#' + current_select_list + ' option:selected').val() + '}}'.length);
     }
     else
         $(this).data('clicks', 1);
     });

 $('.variables_select').focusout(function () {
     $(this).data('clicks', 0);
 });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name="email_admin" class="form-control variables_select" id="myselect">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="user_name">User name</option>
        <option value="ticket_number">Ticket #</option>
        <option value="ticket_subject">Ticket subject</option>
    </select>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="input-group pull-right margin-bottom-1">
            <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @roman Has your problem been solved? let me know if there is problem

Comment: Alireza Ahmadi, thank you very much for your help. Now I understand the problem. Your example is working like a charm! It save my time!

Comment: Only faced with problem when I used Select2 plugin for select list. Click function dose not run.

Comment: @roman You can use `onSelect`. See this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637696/11359076

Comment: Alireza Ahmadi, thanks.  do not understand how to implement it to my example.

Comment: It's hard to explain in comment .You can ask another question with focusing on select2 and I am going to explain there with a working sample

Comment: Ok. asked a question .

Answer (score -1):

Here is a somewhat simplified version that hopefully helps you clean up your code and get you to where you need to be:

```js
$('.variables_select').change(function() {
  var selectedOptionValue = $(this).val();
  var textAreaElement = $("#ta")[0];
  var textAreaValue = $(textAreaElement).val();
  var newTextAreaValue = textAreaValue + "\n" + selectedOptionValue;
  $(textAreaElement).val(newTextAreaValue);
  $('.variables_select').val("");// This line resets the select so you can choose the same option again.
});
```

```css
#ta {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="email_admin" class="form-control variables_select">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="user_name">User name</option>
  <option value="ticket_number">Ticket #</option>
  <option value="ticket_subject">Ticket subject</option>
</select>

<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please check the edited answer. You can now select same option multiple times consecutively.

Comment: Your answer is good but I think OP don't want to reset the value of select box. Because maybe he uses the value in other cases